# Handling Dynamic Xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am automating things using Selenium. Need your help to handle Dynamic Xpath as below:

`Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='INQ_2985']/div[2]/tr/td/div/div[3]/div")).click();`

As above `INQ_2985` changes to `2986`,`2987`,`2988` etc during each run

HTML CODE:

```
< div> class="context-menu-item-inner" style="background-image:url(../images/productSmall.png);">Tender Assignment < /div>
```

Tried different combinations as below but with no success:

```
// Driver.findElement(By.name("//input[@name='Tender Assignment']")).click();
//  Driver.findElement(By.className("context-menu-item-inner")).click();`
```

Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `contains()` or `starts-with()` in xpath,

above xpath can be rewritten as follows,

> Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'INQ')]/div[2]/tr/td/div/div[3]/div")).click();

if you can post more of your html, we can help improve your xpath..

- moreover using such long xpath's is not recommended, this may cause your test to fail more often

> for example,if a "new table data or div" is added to the UI, above xpath will no longer be valid

- you should try and use id, class or other attributes to get closer to the element your trying to find
- i personally recommend using `cssSelectors` over `xpath`

Answer (score 1):

you can use many methods,
use implicity wait;

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'select2-result-label-535')]").click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'select2-result-label-535')]").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to use Regular expression

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'INQ_')]")
```

Note: If you have single ID with name starts from INQ_ then you can take action on the element . If a bunch of ID then you can extract as a `List<WebElements>` and then match with the specific text of the element ( `element.getText().trim() =="Linked Text"` and if it matched then take action. You can follow other logic to traverse and match.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css -

```
div.context-menu-item-inner
```

Use this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.context-menu-item-inner").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your xpath is varying

Ex: `"//*[@id='msg500']" , "//*[@id='msg501']", "//*[@id='msg502']"` and so on...

Then use this code in script:

```
for (int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
String mpath= "//*[@id='msg50"+i+"']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(mpath)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is using full xpath instead of id which you can get easily via firebug.

e.g.

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]
```